# how to delete S3 particular prefix life cycle from python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to delete the particular prefix life cycle by using python boto3

I have tried the below code, but below code is deleting the entire bucket life cycle configuration.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.delete_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket='my_bucket_name')
```

I want to delete the particular prefix life cycle.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify... Are you wanting to delete a Bucket Policy (used to grant access to an Amazon S3 bucket) or are you wanting to modify the bucket Lifecycle rules (used for archiving/deleting objects are a set period of time)?

Answer (score 3):

The `delete_bucket_policy()` API call will delete a **Bucket Policy**, which is used to grant access to an Amazon S3 bucket.

It seems that you actually wish to delete a **Lifecycle policy**, which can be done with the `delete_bucket_lifecycle()` API call.